# Send continuous response to ionic 4 plugin from Wifi device

Tags: java, typescript

I want to send continuous responses getting from device to Ionic 4 plugin from android side.
How can I perform this?

Comment: it's a good approach if you share what you have tried to address this issue. The details which you have provided is not enough to give precise answer .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.